# Openwhisk: increase number of concurrent requests

Tags: serverless, openwhisk

I have a distributed Openwhisk setup, and when I try to execute more than 30 requests with one user at once, I get the following error:

> error: Unable to invoke action 'prime-number': Too many concurrent
>   requests in flight (count: 30, allowed: 30)

Any idea how I could increase this number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using ansible method for deploying OpenWhisk, you can deploy with the following ansible-playbook environment variables override

```
-e limit_invocations_per_minute=999999 -e limit_invocations_concurrent=999999
```

If you are doing other type of deployment, the controller container needs to be deploy with the corresponding environment variables set to override any of these related values.

```
  "LIMITS_ACTIONS_INVOKES_PERMINUTE": "{{ limits.invocationsPerMinute }}"
  "LIMITS_ACTIONS_INVOKES_CONCURRENT": "{{ limits.concurrentInvocations }}"
  "LIMITS_TRIGGERS_FIRES_PERMINUTE": "{{ limits.firesPerMinute }}"
  "LIMITS_ACTIONS_SEQUENCE_MAXLENGTH": "{{ limits.sequenceMaxLength }}"
```

Comment: Where exactly do I add `-e limit_invocations_per_minute=999999`? Or how do I set the environment variables of the controller container? ...I am using gradle to run my openwhisk. Does that mean that I'm using the ansible method?

Comment: I tried modifying `ansible/roles/controller/tasks/deploy.yml` but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @csantanapr answer, you can add them to openwhisk.yml playbook.

```
ansible-playbook -i environments/<environment>  -e limit_invocations_per_minute=999999 -e limit_invocations_concurrent=999999 openwhisk.yml
```

Comment: Where exactly do I add `-e limit_invocations_per_minute=999999`? Which file? I don't think we add it to `openwhisk.yml` itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the non-ansible method to run openwhisk, you can refer to [the issue here](https://github.com/apache/openwhisk/issues/5182). You can also refer to [this](https://github.com/apache/openwhisk/tree/master/core/standalone).

You can modify the file `core/standalone/src/main/resources/standalone.conf`. If you look at this part:

```
config {
  controller-instances = 1
  limits-actions-sequence-maxLength = 50
  limits-triggers-fires-perMinute = 60
  limits-actions-invokes-perMinute = 60
  limits-actions-invokes-concurrent = 30
}
```

you can modify the value of `limits-actions-invokes-concurrent` and any of the other limits.

Then, when you run openwhisk, you need to supply the file through the `-c` parameter, through the `--args` parameter. Like so:

```
sudo ./gradlew core:standalone:bootRun --args='-c /path/to/openwhisk/core/standalone/src/main/resources/standalone.conf'
```

That's it.

---

You can also "build then run", like so:

```
sudo ./gradlew :core:standalone:build
sudo java -jar ./bin/openwhisk-standalone.jar -c /path/to/openwhisk/core/standalone/src/main/resources/standalone.conf
```